# How can I extract a value from an object in a Swift 3 array and compare or map it to a value from a different object in a different array?

Tags: arrays, swift3

This is my scenario

> let arrayA = [ObjectA]
>   let arrayB = [ObjectB]
>
> arrayA.count = arrayB.count
>
> ObjectA != ObjectB
>
> objectA.someProperty = objectB.someOtherProperty

I want to conditionally map objects in arrayA to objects in arrayB based on their common property value but am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I managed this:

```
for objectA in arrayA {
    let someProperty = objectA.someProperty
    for objectB in arrayB {
        if objectB.someOtherProperty == someProperty {
            // run code that maps objectB to objectA
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really intend, but you can write something like this:

```
class ObjectA {
    var someProperty: String

    init(someProperty: String) {
        self.someProperty = someProperty
    }
}

class ObjectB {
    var someOtherProperty: String

    init(someOtherProperty: String) {
        self.someOtherProperty = someOtherProperty
    }
}

let arrayA: [ObjectA] = [
    ObjectA(someProperty: "a"),
    ObjectA(someProperty: "b"),
    ObjectA(someProperty: "c"),
]
let arrayB: [ObjectB] = [
    ObjectB(someOtherProperty: "A"),
    ObjectB(someOtherProperty: "B"),
    ObjectB(someOtherProperty: "C"),
]

assert(arrayA.count == arrayB.count)

zip(arrayA, arrayB).forEach{ objectA, objectB in objectA.someProperty = objectB.someOtherProperty }
```

Or simply using for-in:

```
for i in arrayA.indices {
    let objectA = arrayA[i]
    let objectB = arrayB[i]
    objectA.someProperty = objectB.someOtherProperty
}
```

I do not know any other simpler notation than above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I needed to do was to conditionally map the objects based on their common property value, not set the property values to be identical.

Comment: @tolkienfan2, hmm...n, do you think readers can guess what you really need from your post? You'd better edit your question and clarify your requirement.

Comment: I'm sorry @OOPer, I have edited my original post to hopefully be clearer to everyone - I was trying to be clear from the start, but obviously didn't succeed!  My answer to my question, which I only discovered after trying many different things, works perfectly for the purpose.

Comment: @tolkienfan2, thanks for updating your question and reporting. One bad thing, making your code hard to read, is your usage of `=`. You use single `=` for both assignment and comparison. If you used `==` for comparison, your question could be far clearer. But the best thing to clarify your intention is adding some code, like in your _answer_. That sort of code should be in your **_question_**, not in your _answer_. I understand that sort of code might not be ready when you posted your question, but even an incomplete code would help improving your question.

Comment: @tolkienfan2, your code is not efficient when the number of element in the two arrays are huge. (Takes O(n^2) ... if you like big-O notation.) if you clarify some conditions, it can be improved. (For example, `someOtherProperty` and `someProperty` are `Hashable` then you can find matching `ObjectB` far quicker than your code.) Anyway, it's your choice. If you have some interest in improving efficiency of your code, please add comment.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice, I see what you mean in how to clarify my intention and will remember that for my future posts.

Comment: My arrays are not huge actually, only a handful of elements, so I think my code should be ok? I haven't yet learned what hashables are, but I'm sure what you say about using them is correct for huge arrays and will certainly look into learning more about this when I finish this present app I'm working on. Thanks again.

Comment: @tolkienfan2, I see. The best may be affected by the number. Good luck for you and for your app.